# Generate SHA-224 hash in Java on Android

Tags: java, android

Is there any method to generate SHA-224 hash of a string in Java on Android?

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-224")
```

throws `NoSuchAlgorithmException`

Thanks for help.

Comment: "doesn't work for me" what is the problem?

Comment: prolly NoSuchAlgorithmException

Comment: Sorry, I meant NoSuchAlgorithmException. Thx to Selvin

Comment: A search for `java sha-224` turns up resources like: https://gist.github.com/upsuper/3012171

Comment: I tried this implementation but result of hashing isn't correct. Code: 

`MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-224", "SHA224Provider");
md.update(orig.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] result = md.digest();
String hash = new String(result);`

I always get wrong hash (compared with online sha224 generator) :/

Comment: Please check comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647675/how-create-sha224sum-in-java