# How create SHA224SUM in java

Tags: java, android, sha

I need create hash from my string using analog Linux command SHA224SUM in java under Android.

I try use:

```
      MessageDigest messageDigest224 = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-224");
      byte[] bSHA224 = messageDigest224.digest( "hello word".getBytes());
```

But I get error

```
      MessageDigest SHA-224 implementation not found
      java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MessageDigest SHA-224 implementation not found
```

SHA-512, SHA-1 algorithm work fine.

Please get me link to analog SHA224 in Java. Please any ideas.

Comment: Works for me (part of SUN provider in Java 8) - which JDK version are you using?

Comment: As of JDK8 SHA-224 is available out of the box. For earlier versions you could provide your own implementation: https://gist.github.com/upsuper/3012171

Comment: SSH-224 has been added in Java 8, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest versus http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

Comment: I'm sorry. I need solution under Android. I add to question

Comment: that are solutions for andoird too. Change sdk or use own implementation.

Comment: did you read the Crozin's comment? he pointed you to an implementations of that algorithm on github. If the licence terms allows to use it then you could bundle it in your application.

Comment: @kai, how I can change sdk in my Eclipse and Java? Now I have Win7 + Java 8 update 25 + Eclipse (Kepler) with all last updates.